# How to set up multiple configurations of the same object graph with Guice?

Tags: java, guice

How would you build up the object graph shown in the diagram below?

The user object must combine the information from the two data base backends.

[image: Multiple configurations of the same object graph]

Comment: See [How do I build two similar but slightly different trees of objects?](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using private modules.

```
static class Service {
    @Inject Dao daoA;

    public void doSomething() {
        daoA.doA();
    }
}

static class Dao {
    @Inject DataSource dataSource;

    public void doA() {
        dataSource.execute();
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface Connection {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface X {}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface Y {}

static class DataSource {
    @Connection @Inject String connection;

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("execute on: " + connection);
    }
}

static class XServiceModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Service.class).annotatedWith(X.class).to(Service.class);
        expose(Service.class).annotatedWith(X.class);

        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Connection.class).to("http://server1");
    }
}

static class YServiceModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Service.class).annotatedWith(Y.class).to(Service.class);
        expose(Service.class).annotatedWith(Y.class);

        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Connection.class).to("http://server2");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new XServiceModule(), new YServiceModule()); 

    Service serviceX = injector.getInstance(Key.get(Service.class, X.class));  
    serviceX.doSomething(); 

    Service serviceY = injector.getInstance(Key.get(Service.class, Y.class));
    serviceY.doSomething(); 
}
```

- The different instances of the Service class can be identified by X and Y annotation.
- By hiding all other dependencies in the private module there are no collisions between Dao and DataSource
- In the two private modules it is possible to bind the Constant in two different ways
- The services are exposed through expose.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you should use the [assisted injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) extension to Guice to generate a factory that takes a `Service` to a `DataSource`, and then apply that factory to two different `Service`s.

Comment: Um.  As explained, create a factory that takes a `Service` to a `DataSource`, as explained in the linked wiki article.

Comment: Could you provide some details? The example in the wiki article is about creating domain objects with link to services. My problem is not in domain object space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BindingAnnotations or simply the generic @Named Annotation for this. I find them simpliest to use with @Provides-Methods:

```
@Provides
@Named("User1")
public SomeUser getUser(Service1 service) {
   return service.getUser();
}
@Provides
@Named("User2")
public SomeUser getUser(Service2 service) {
   return service.getUser();
}
```

and then:

```
@Inject
@Named("User1")
private SomeUser someuser;
...
```

Comment: The left objects and the right objects have the same types. Especially Service is just one class. Should i name all objects in the graph?

Comment: Ok, that was not clear to me ... You can still work with Provides Methods.

How to you want to decide which service to use?

Comment: in Spring i would decide this by name. The robot leg example brought me to the 2 annotations X and Y...